# How to get all elements which name starts with some string?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page. I would like to extract all elements whose name starts with "q1_".

How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

Comment: Do you mean the tag name or the value of a `name` attribute?

Comment: Are all the elements in question of the same type of tag?  Are they all DIVs, or LIs for example?

Comment: Yes, all elements are of type "input".

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A quick and easy way is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and do this:

```
var $eles = $(":input[name^='q1_']").css("color","yellow");
```

That will grab all elements whose *name* attribute starts with 'q1_'. To convert the resulting collection of jQuery objects to a DOM collection, do this:

```
var DOMeles = $eles.get();
```

see http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

In pure DOM, you could use `getElementsByTagName` to grab all input elements, and loop through the resulting array. Elements with `name` starting with 'q1_' get pushed to another array:

```
var eles = [];
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].name.indexOf('q1_') == 0) {
        eles.push(inputs[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Varun, the second code snipped in karim79's answer is plain javascript, he's not using jQuery.

Comment: Nice answer, except you need `.css("color", "yellow");`, as `font-color` doesn't exist in css. I make this mistake very often as well. :P

Answer (score 27):

HTML DOM querySelectorAll() method seems apt here.

W3School Link given [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp)

Syntax (As given in W3School)

```
document.querySelectorAll(CSS selectors)
```

So the answer.

```
document.querySelectorAll("[name^=q1_]")
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paje007/nab4tLxk/2/)

Edit:

Considering FLX's suggestion adding link to MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

Comment: This is the most apt way to do it.

Answer (score 21):

You can use getElementsByName("input") to get a collection of all the inputs on the page.  Then loop through the collection, checking the name on the way. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<body>

  <input name="q1_a" type="text" value="1A"/>
  <input name="q1_b" type="text" value="1B"/>
  <input name="q1_c" type="text" value="1C"/>
  <input name="q2_d" type="text" value="2D"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (x = 0 ; x < inputs.length ; x++){
    myname = inputs[x].getAttribute("name");
    if(myname.indexOf("q1_")==0){
      alert(myname);
      // do more stuff here
       }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/uhego)

Comment: @Varun what's inefficient about this?

Comment: u will have to iterate on all input elements. i mean something better can be done?

Comment: also you may need to check nyname for null if(myname != null){ ... } before doing something with it, otherwise your script will cancel when meets it.

Comment: There is an error in the code. The for loop should loop only while (x<inputs.length) holds true, not <=. Also as said before, you need to check myname for null.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure java-script, here is a working code example

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit1" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit2" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit3" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="other1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="other2" checked />
<br>
<input type="button" name="check" value="count checked checkboxes name starts with fruit*" onClick="checkboxes();" />


<script>
function checkboxes()
{
var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
count = 0;
for (var i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {       
if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked == true && 
inputElems[i].name.indexOf('fruit') == 0) 
{
count++;

}

}
alert(count);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) with the [Attribute Contains Prefix Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/).

```
$('[id|=q1_]')
```

Haven't tested it though.

Comment: The `[attr|=value]` selector is supposed to be used for language identifiers.