# What is the DOM/Vanilla Javascript equivalent of jquery's .is(':empty')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a snippet of code that will traverse the document.body of a page and report all empty block level DOM nodes. This is a pass for SEO/a11y.

I found this article that will seemingly help:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/check-for-empty-elements/

```
$('*').each(function() {
         if ($(this).is(':empty') == "") {
                   //Do Something
         }
});
```

Question #1: How would I convert `.is(':empty')` to vanilla js:

```
function isEmpty(el) {
  // Robust isEmpty logic here
}
document.querySelectorAll('*').filter(el => {
  return isEmpty(el);
});
```

Question #2: Will this logic traverse all children too?

Question #3: Could we make this querySelector for only blocklevel elements?

Comment: On SO, it's important to ask **one** question per question, not three. Question #3 above, in particular, is quite far afield from Question #1.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the semantic clarification on Javascript/Jquery over DOM I've updated the Question's Title.  And Yes one question per question, sorry for over stepping the SO rules. Moreover, thanks for giving such a clear answer.  Great job!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [**DOM**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) version of "empty" is that there are no child nodes, which you can check in various ways, probably the two most common are:

- [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) will be `null` if there are no child nodes
- The `length` of [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) will be `0` if there are no child nodes

So for instance, since `null` is falsy and `filter` works with truthy/falsy values:

```
const allEmpty = [...document.querySelectorAll('*')].filter(el => !el.firstChild);
```

(Note that `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` and `NodeList` doesn't have a `filter` method, so I used spread notation there to create an array from the `NodeList` [since `NodeList`s are *iterable* according to the spec now; but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057817/157247) about ensuring that `NodeList` is *iterable* in your environment].)

> Question #2: Will this logic traverse all children too?

`querySelectorAll('*')` selects **every** element in the document, many of which will be inside others also on the list.

> Question #3: Could we make this querySelector for only blocklevel elements?

You can certainly tailor it according to the current specification and the default `display` browsers apply to them by doing a list of tag, such as `querySelectorAll("div, p, h1"/*...*/)`. But that doesn't tell you what's a block element **on that page**, since CSS can change the `display` of elements. To get up-to-date information, you'd need to use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) on each element after selecting it and check the `display` of the result.

Building a list of **all** of the elements on a page may not be ideal, you might consider a recursive function instead:

```
function findEmpty(element, results = []) {
    let child = element.firstChild;
    if (!child) {
        results.push(element);
    }
    while (child) {
        if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            findEmpty(child, results);
        }
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
    return results;
}
const allEmpty = findEmpty(document.body);
```

---

But this partially comes down to what you consider "empty." jQuery's `:empty` selector is quite literal: An element is only empty if it doesn't have any child nodes. But your definition may be more loose — for instance, perhaps you want to consider an element that contains only whitespace (directly or in descendant elements) "empty" for your purposes (in which case: `!el.textContent.trim()`). The first link above is to the DOM information on MDN which gives you lots to explore to determine your own "empty" if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `children` which is different from `childNodes` which can contain any node including text node. If using `childNodes.length` on `div` like `<div>Some  Text here</div>` will be return a non empty array even though there is no child element or html tags

```js
function isEmpty(el) {
  return el.children.length
}
[...document.querySelectorAll('div.parent')].filter(function(el) {
  let k = isEmpty(el);
  console.log(k)
});
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 1</div>
</div>

<div class='parent'></div>
```

Comment: But who would consider `<div>Lots of text here</div>` "empty"?

Comment: I think `childnodes` on this text will a non empty array if objective is to select only child elements but not text nodes

Comment: Right. What I'm saying is that the div above is not empty, but if you use `children`, it'll get reported as empty.