# Click a nav item, add a class, remove class from other nav items - vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I'm able to add a class of `is-active` to a nav item when it's clicked. However, i'd like to remove the class and add it to another nav item when another is clicked.

Here's what I'm currently working with:

JS:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

links.forEach(function(link, index){
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(this.classList.contains('is-active')) {
      this.classList.remove('is-active');
    } else {
      this.classList.add('is-active');
    }
  });
});
```

[Here's a Codepen example.](https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/99a9d81491b043df7e1343210dae4077)

This attempt adds the class, but doesn't remove it when another link is clicked.

How would I remove the class? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just loop through the links that aren't `this`:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

links.forEach(function(link, index){
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(this.classList.contains('is-active')) {
      this.classList.remove('is-active');
    } else {
      this.classList.add('is-active');
      links.forEach(l => {                     // ***
          if (l !== this) {                    // ***
              l.classList.remove('is-active'); // ***
          }                                    // ***
      });
    }
  });
});
```

(See below for the `for-of` version.)

Alternately, you can do a new query of just the `is-active` links:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(link, index){
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(this.classList.contains('is-active')) {
      this.classList.remove('is-active');
    } else {
      document.querySelectorAll('a.is-active').forEach(activeLink => { // ***
          activeLink.classList.remove('is-active');                    // ***
      });                                                              // ***
      this.classList.add('is-active');
    }
  });
});
```

Or if you like, since there should be only one, `querySelector`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(link, index){
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(this.classList.contains('is-active')) {
      this.classList.remove('is-active');
    } else {
      const activeLink = document.querySelector('a.is-active'); // **
      if (activeLink) {                                         // **
          activeLink.classList.remove('is-active');             // **
      }                                                         // **
      this.classList.add('is-active');
    }
  });
});
```

---

Side note: The `NodeList` from `querySelectorAll` doesn't have `forEach` in some browsers (it was added relatively recently). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057817/157247) for how to add it if it's missing, and (on ES2015+ platforms) how to ensure it's iterable as well (as it's also meant to be).

---

And if you can rely on iterability, here are `for-of` versions of those:

`for-of` version of the first example:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (const link of links) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(this.classList.contains('is-active')) {
      this.classList.remove('is-active');
    } else {
      this.classList.add('is-active');
      for (const l of links) {
          if (l !== this) {
              l.classList.remove('is-active');
          }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

`for-of` version of the second example:

```
for (const link of document.querySelectorAll('a')) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(this.classList.contains('is-active')) {
      this.classList.remove('is-active');
    } else {
      for (const activeLink of document.querySelectorAll('a.is-active')) {
          activeLink.classList.remove('is-active');
      }
      this.classList.add('is-active');
    }
  });
}
```

And the third:

```
for (const link of document.querySelectorAll('a')) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(this.classList.contains('is-active')) {
      this.classList.remove('is-active');
    } else {
      const activeLink = document.querySelector('a.is-active'); // **
      if (activeLink) {                                         // **
          activeLink.classList.remove('is-active');             // **
      }                                                         // **
      this.classList.add('is-active');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common requirement - you can do this:

- get an *iterable representation* of the *DOM Elements* using [**`spread syntax`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like `[...document.querySelectorAll('a')]`
- use [**`forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to *loop* through the links
- you can use the `classList.toggle` function instead of having the if-else conditions

See demo below:

```js
// get an iterable representation using the spread syntax
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')];

elements.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // remove active class from all links
  elements.forEach(e => e.classList.remove('is-active'));
  // add active to the clicked link
  e.classList.toggle('is-active');
}));
```

```css
.is-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the function refers to the elements that is clicked. You should hide all the elements every time using `forEach` in each click. And then show the desired one

```
const links = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')];

links.forEach(function(link, index){
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let temp = this.classList.contains('is-active')
    links.forEach(x => x.classList.remove('is-active'))
    if(!temp) {
      this.classList.add('is-active');
    } 
  });
});
```