# Apply style with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

I created the next code:

```js
  setTimeout(function () {
        var dot = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
        for (var i=0;i<dot.length;i++) {
            dot[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        }
    },2000);
```

```css
 .container{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
   .dot{
       background-color: red;
       width: 20px;
       height: 20px;
       border-radius: 50%;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div  class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot" ></div>
<div class="dot" ></div>
</div>
```

This code apply background-color for each dot at the same time after 2 seconds, but i want to apply the style for each dot separately. Fo example: after 2 seconds to apply the style for first dot, then after 2 seconds to apply the style for second dot, and so on. Who has a solution?

Comment: you can use setInterval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is to create separate timers, making each wait `2000`ms longer than the last by multiplying by the loop index:

```
var dot = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
for (let i=0;i<dot.length;i++) { // ***
    setTimeout(function () {
        dot[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }, i * 2000);
}
```

Note also the use of `let` rather than `var` in the loop, so that each loop iteration gets its own copy of `i`. If you can't use ES2015 features, see [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for how to deal with `i` in the `for` loop.

If we're using ES2015, we may as well use a `for-of` loop instead:

```
let i = 0;
for (const dot of document.querySelectorAll('.dot')) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        dot.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }, i++ * 2000);
}
```

That relies on the `NodeList` from `querySelectorAll` being iterable, which it is on modern browsers. I don't know if there are any browsers with ES2015 but which don't (yet) make `NodeList` iterable; if there are any, you can use [this answer's technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057817/157247) to add iterability.

Answer (score 2):

Put the setTimeout inside the for loop and the multiply `i` with 2000 to set different interval

```js
var dot = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
for (let i = 0; i < dot.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    dot[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }, i * 2000);

}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.dot {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var i = 0;
  var dot = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    dot[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    i++;
    if (i >= dot.length) clearInterval(interval);
  },2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the long way: ```    
    setTimeout(function () {
        var dot = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');

````
    setTimeout(function () {
        for (var i=0;i<dot.length;i++) {
        dot[0].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        }

        setTimeout(function () {
            for (var i=0;i<dot.length;i++) {
            dot[1].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
            }
        },2000);

    },2000);
},2000);    
</script>```
````

But i would suggest (i * 2000)

Answer (score 0):

Try using setInterval, seems to be perfect for your case.

```
    var dotNumber = 0;
    var myVar = setInterval(() => {
        var dot = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
        dot[dotNumber].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

        dotNumber +=1; 

        if (dotNumber >= dot.length){
           clearInterval(myVar);
        }  
     }, 2000);
```