# Get text content of 3rd <p> element inside of <div> . With several div containers with the same name

Tags: javascript, html, widget

I have the following code.

```js
    var bTags = document.getElementsByClassName("Wrapper");
    var kind = bTags[0];
    console.log(kind);
    console.log(kind.childNodes[4].text);
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
        <h3 class="date" id="date">{{date}}</h3>
    <div class="descriptionWrapper">
        <p class="jobDescription">{{job}}</p>
        <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p>
        <p class="placeDescription">{{ort}}</p>
        <p class="kindDescription">{{anstellung}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jobLink">
        {{#custom_link jobLink}}
            {{linkText}}
        {{/custom_link}}
    </div>
</div>
```

In my example the "console.log(kind);" successfully logs the HTML object. Here its not working of course because its not defined. But somehow the childNodes[4].text is undefined. I just want to access the text of the p element with the class "placeDescription" of this specific parentNode. A static try like the following is not possible because I have several HTML ".Wrapper" objects who just differ by content.
I think I can access them by just writing the p elements into divs and then with ChildNodes but thats not very clean imo. Why is kind.childNodes[4].text undefined when kind is not ?

`const el = document.querySelector('.Wrapper p:nth-of-type(3)');
if (el) {
 console.log(el.textContent)
}`

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: It's `.textContent` afaik, not `.text`

Comment: Oh wow thanks . What a trifle ! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would work if you changed `text` to `textContent` (or `innerText` on old IE, but it's not quite the same thing) and `4` to `3`. **But**, it's fragile. You can be more precise with `querySelector`:

```
var div = document.querySelector(".Wrapper div");
console.log(div.textContent);
```

Live Example:

```js
var div = document.querySelector(".Wrapper div");
console.log(div.textContent);
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
        <h3 class="date" id="date">{{date}}</h3>
    <div class="descriptionWrapper">
        <p class="jobDescription">{{job}}</p>
        <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p>
        <p class="placeDescription">{{ort}}</p>
        <p class="kindDescription">{{anstellung}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jobLink">
        {{#custom_link jobLink}}
            {{linkText}}
        {{/custom_link}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Live your version, that only looks at the **first** such match. If you want all of them, you'll need a loop:

```
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".Wrapper"); // Or .getElementsByClassName("Wrapper");
for (var i = 0; i < wrappers.length; ++i) {
    var div = wrappers[i].querySelector("div");
    console.log(div.textContent);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".Wrapper"); // Or .getElementsByClassName("Wrapper");
for (var i = 0; i < wrappers.length; ++i) {
    var div = wrappers[i].querySelector("div");
    console.log(div.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
        <h3 class="date" id="date">{{date}}</h3>
    <div class="descriptionWrapper">
        <p class="jobDescription">{{job}} first</p>
        <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p>
        <p class="placeDescription">{{ort}}</p>
        <p class="kindDescription">{{anstellung}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jobLink">
        {{#custom_link jobLink}}
            {{linkText}}
        {{/custom_link}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Wrapper">
        <h3 class="date" id="date">{{date}}</h3>
    <div class="descriptionWrapper">
        <p class="jobDescription">{{job}} second</p>
        <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p>
        <p class="placeDescription">{{ort}}</p>
        <p class="kindDescription">{{anstellung}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jobLink">
        {{#custom_link jobLink}}
            {{linkText}}
        {{/custom_link}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Wrapper">
        <h3 class="date" id="date">{{date}}</h3>
    <div class="descriptionWrapper">
        <p class="jobDescription">{{job}} third</p>
        <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p>
        <p class="placeDescription">{{ort}}</p>
        <p class="kindDescription">{{anstellung}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jobLink">
        {{#custom_link jobLink}}
            {{linkText}}
        {{/custom_link}}
    </div>
</div>
```

In a modern browser (or with the polyfill approach [I describe in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057817/157247)), you can use `forEach` instead of the `for` loop (or even `for-of` in ES2015+), which makes it a bit more concise:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".Wrapper").forEach(function(wrapper) {
    var div = wrapper.querySelector("div");
    console.log(div.textContent);
});
```

Live Example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".Wrapper").forEach(function(wrapper) {
    var div = wrapper.querySelector("div");
    console.log(div.textContent);
});
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
        <h3 class="date" id="date">{{date}}</h3>
    <div class="descriptionWrapper">
        <p class="jobDescription">{{job}} first</p>
        <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p>
        <p class="placeDescription">{{ort}}</p>
        <p class="kindDescription">{{anstellung}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jobLink">
        {{#custom_link jobLink}}
            {{linkText}}
        {{/custom_link}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Wrapper">
        <h3 class="date" id="date">{{date}}</h3>
    <div class="descriptionWrapper">
        <p class="jobDescription">{{job}} second</p>
        <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p>
        <p class="placeDescription">{{ort}}</p>
        <p class="kindDescription">{{anstellung}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jobLink">
        {{#custom_link jobLink}}
            {{linkText}}
        {{/custom_link}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Wrapper">
        <h3 class="date" id="date">{{date}}</h3>
    <div class="descriptionWrapper">
        <p class="jobDescription">{{job}} third</p>
        <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p>
        <p class="placeDescription">{{ort}}</p>
        <p class="kindDescription">{{anstellung}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jobLink">
        {{#custom_link jobLink}}
            {{linkText}}
        {{/custom_link}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Or with ES2015+ (again, you may need to do some [polyfilling per above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057817/157247)):

```
for (const wrapper of document.querySelectorAll(".Wrapper")) {
    const div = wrapper.querySelector("div");
    console.log(div.textContent);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
for (const wrapper of document.querySelectorAll(".Wrapper")) {
    const div = wrapper.querySelector("div");
    console.log(div.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
        <h3 class="date" id="date">{{date}}</h3>
    <div class="descriptionWrapper">
        <p class="jobDescription">{{job}} first</p>
        <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p>
        <p class="placeDescription">{{ort}}</p>
        <p class="kindDescription">{{anstellung}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jobLink">
        {{#custom_link jobLink}}
            {{linkText}}
        {{/custom_link}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Wrapper">
        <h3 class="date" id="date">{{date}}</h3>
    <div class="descriptionWrapper">
        <p class="jobDescription">{{job}} second</p>
        <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p>
        <p class="placeDescription">{{ort}}</p>
        <p class="kindDescription">{{anstellung}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jobLink">
        {{#custom_link jobLink}}
            {{linkText}}
        {{/custom_link}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Wrapper">
        <h3 class="date" id="date">{{date}}</h3>
    <div class="descriptionWrapper">
        <p class="jobDescription">{{job}} third</p>
        <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p>
        <p class="placeDescription">{{ort}}</p>
        <p class="kindDescription">{{anstellung}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jobLink">
        {{#custom_link jobLink}}
            {{linkText}}
        {{/custom_link}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought about this aswell. Thank you Sir ! Il will try it out .