# sort dom elements on the basis of href attribute in JS

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have DOM elements as shown below. I want to sort it on the basis of href attribute.

This is what I have tried in **JS** but more need to be done.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    let elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".house-senate a"));
    elems.sort((a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent));

});
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what JS code I need to add so that it sorts everything on the basis of href attributes.

Comment: It should sort on the basis of **category** present inside **href** attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, but:

- You need to actually move them in the DOM.
- You're potentially sorting ones that aren't in the same parent (though they all are in your example HTML).
- [blex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913729/blex) pointed out to me that you want to sort by the `category` in the `href`, not by the `href` itself. In your example, it comes to the same thing because the text prior to the category in all the `href`s is the same, but still, perhaps better to extract it.

This is blex's function for extracting it:

```
function getLinkCategory(a) {
  const matches = a.href.match(/category=([a-z]+)/i);
  return matches ? matches[1] : '';
}
```

Or if you want to be more rigorous about extracting that parameter from the query string, [this collaborative answer originally by Code Spy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1913729) shows how to do that.

See comments for more:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Get the container
    const container = document.querySelector(".house-senate");
    // Get its immediate child `a` elements
    const elems = [...container.children].filter(child => child.tagName === "A");
    // Sort them
    elems.sort((a, b) => getLinkCategory(a).localeCompare(getLinkCategory(b)));
    // Add them back, which moves them
    for (const el of elems) {
        container.appendChild(el);
    }
});
```

Live Example:

```js
function getLinkCategory(a) {
  const matches = a.href.match(/category=([a-z]+)/i);
  return matches ? matches[1] : '';
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Get the container
    const container = document.querySelector(".house-senate");
    // Get its immediate child `a` elements
    const elems = [...container.children].filter(child => child.tagName === "A");
    // Sort them
    elems.sort((a, b) => getLinkCategory(a).localeCompare(getLinkCategory(b)));
    // Add them back, which moves them
    for (const el of elems) {
        container.appendChild(el);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="house-senate widget widget-cpac-depth -horizontal">
    <h1 class="widget__title">Committees</h1>
    <a href="/en/?s=&amp;category=BOIE">
        <div class="committee">
            <div class="color-green">BOIE</div>
            <p>Board of Internal Economy</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/en/?s=&amp;category=CACN">
        <div class="committee">
            <div class="color-green">CACN</div>
            <p>Canada-China Relations</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/en/?s=&amp;category=CHPC">
        <div class="committee">
            <div class="color-green">CHPC</div>
            <p>Canadian Heritage</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/en/?s=&amp;category=CIIT">
        <div class="committee">
            <div class="color-green">CIIT</div>
            <p>International Trade</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

If you need to add more sorting criteria (per your comment under the question), just add them in the `sort` callback; [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields) has answers showing how to sort an array of objects on multiple criteria.

I've assumed above that there aren't hundreds of these links. If there are, and **if** you see a performance problem with the above, you can remove the container from the DOM before moving the links around within it, then put it back:

Live Example:

```js
function getLinkCategory(a) {
  const matches = a.href.match(/category=([a-z]+)/i);
  return matches ? matches[1] : '';
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Get the container
    const container = document.querySelector(".house-senate");
    // Remember its parent and following sibling and remove it
    const parent = container.parentNode;
    const sibling = container.nextSibling;
    parent.removeChild(container);
    // Get its immediate child `a` elements
    const elems = [...container.children].filter(child => child.tagName === "A");
    // Sort them
    elems.sort((a, b) => getLinkCategory(a).localeCompare(getLinkCategory(b)));
    // Add them back, which moves them
    for (const el of elems) {
        container.appendChild(el);
    }
    // Put the container back -- note this works even if the
    // container was the last child in the parent
    // and `sibling` is `null`.
    parent.insertBefore(container, sibling);
});
```

```html
<div>This is before the <code>div</code> with the links in it.</div>
<div class="house-senate widget widget-cpac-depth -horizontal">
    <h1 class="widget__title">Committees</h1>
    <a href="/en/?s=&amp;category=BOIE">
        <div class="committee">
            <div class="color-green">BOIE</div>
            <p>Board of Internal Economy</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/en/?s=&amp;category=CACN">
        <div class="committee">
            <div class="color-green">CACN</div>
            <p>Canada-China Relations</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/en/?s=&amp;category=CHPC">
        <div class="committee">
            <div class="color-green">CHPC</div>
            <p>Canadian Heritage</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/en/?s=&amp;category=CIIT">
        <div class="committee">
            <div class="color-green">CIIT</div>
            <p>International Trade</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div>This is after the <code>div</code> with the links in it.</div>
```

---

Note: You're using modern language features, but the above relies on a modern *browser* feature (`NodeList` being iterable). If you're transpiling, it may not be that all the browsers you're targeting have the necessary feature, but for anything even *vaguely* modern, you can polyfill it; see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057817/157247) for details.

Comment: He needs to sort them based on the caregory in the `href` attribute. See my _(deleted)_ answer

Comment: @blex - Ah, thanks, I misread the comment about that! Although actually, since the text prior to `category` is the same in all the `href`s, sorting by `href` does sort by `category`... :-)

Comment: Indeed it does :) Note: this extracting function is very basic and will only extract letters. A more complete way of doing it would be [this answer by Code Spy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1913729)