# Filtering a table by element's name

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter, width

I'm trying to filter this HTML table by writing some text in a search form, which works great but whenever it filters, the elements try to fill the whole width of the table instead of keeping their original element width (25% of the table's width, without counting the spaces between the cells).

```js
function searchFilter () {
   const input = document.getElementById('myInput');
   const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
   const table = document.getElementById('tablaPiola');
   const articule = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

   for (i = 0; i < articule.length; i++) {
      a = articule[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         articule[i].style.display = "";
         } else {
         articule[i].style.display = "none";
         }
   }
}

document.getElementById("filter-btn").addEventListener("click", searchFilter);
```

```css
body {
background-color: black;
}

table
{border-spacing: 20px;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 600px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 10px;}

td
{text-align: center;
border-radius: 10px;}

td a
{width: 100%;
display: block;
line-height: 50px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "Poppins";
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 12px;
color: white;}

.automatizaciones
{background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100/0000FF/0000FF");
background-size: cover;}

.bpm_a_ms
{background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100/0000FF/0000FF");
background-size: cover;}

.compresion
{background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100/0000FF/0000FF");
background-size: cover;}

.compresion_multibanda
{background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100/0000FF/0000FF");
background-size: cover;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<input type="button" id="filter-btn" value="Apply">
<table class="tabla_basico" id="tablaPiola">
   <tr>
      <td class="automatizaciones">
         <div class="overlay_basico"><a href="/">AUTOMATIZACIONES</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="bpm_a_ms">
         <div class="overlay_intermedio"><a href="/">BPM A MS</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="compresion">
         <div class="overlay_basico"><a href="compresion.html">COMPRESIÓN</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="compresion_multibanda">
         <div class="overlay_intermedio"><a href="/">COMPRESIÓN MULTIBANDA</a></div>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

[This is my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phQzu.jpg)

[This is how it filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SNaD.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! **Nice one** including almost all of the relevant HTML, CSS, and JavaScript! I was able to take what you'd provided and create a runnable version in your question using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). For next time, [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). Again, well done including nearly everything needed, and not too much extra.

Comment: I'm just curious: What language is that? It looks a bit like a couple of languages I'm familiar with, but not quite like any of them. :-) Your location argues for Brazilian Portuguese, but `articule` would be `artigos` if I'm not mistaken. `articule` looks Italian, but it would be `articoli`. And Spanish wouldn't use that form of plural. Clearly a romance language, but... I'm just curious, I love languages.

Comment: I'm from Buenos Aires, Argentina so it's Spanish :)

Comment: I'm using some words in english and some in spanish. Thought "articule" was english for "articulo" (spanish) :P

Comment: Ah! In English it's "article" and "articles" :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally thought `visibility: hidden` but you pointed out that that means the ones that are showing aren't on the left anymore.

My only other thought is adding padding cells at the end:

```
function searchFilter () {
   const input = document.getElementById('myInput');
   const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
   const table = document.getElementById('tablaPiola');
   // Remove any fillers we added last time
   table.querySelectorAll(".filler").forEach(filler => {
       filler.parentNode.removeChild(filler);
   });
   const articule = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
   // Remember how many are showing at the end
   let showing = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < articule.length; i++) {
      a = articule[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         articule[i].style.display = "";
         ++showing; // Remember we're showing this one
      } else {
         articule[i].style.display = "none";
      }
   }
   // Grab the length (since `articule` is a live list
   const max = articule.length;
   // Add blank cells to the end
   while (showing < max) {
      const filler = document.createElement("td");
      filler.className = "filler";
      table.appendChild(filler);
      ++showing;
   }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function searchFilter () {
   const input = document.getElementById('myInput');
   const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
   const table = document.getElementById('tablaPiola');
   // Remove any fillers we added last time
   table.querySelectorAll(".filler").forEach(filler => {
       filler.parentNode.removeChild(filler);
   });
   const articule = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
   // Remember how many are showing at the end
   let showing = 0;
   
   for (i = 0; i < articule.length; i++) {
      a = articule[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         articule[i].style.display = "";
         ++showing; // Remember we're showing this one
      } else {
         articule[i].style.display = "none";
      }
   }
   // Grab the length (since `articule` is a live list
   const max = articule.length;
   // Add blank cells to the end
   while (showing < max) {
      const filler = document.createElement("td");
      filler.className = "filler";
      table.appendChild(filler);
      ++showing;
   }
}

document.getElementById("filter-btn").addEventListener("click", searchFilter);
```

```css
body {
background-color: black;
}

table
{border-spacing: 20px;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 1200px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 100px;}

td
{text-align: center;
border-radius: 10px;}

td a
{width: 100%;
display: block;
line-height: 150px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "Poppins";
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 17.5px;
color: white;}

.automatizaciones
{background-image: url(imagenes/basico/automatizaciones/articulo.jpg);
background-size: cover;}

.bpm_a_ms
{background-image: url(imagenes/intermedio/bpm_a_ms/articulo.jpg);
background-size: cover;}

.compresion
{background-image: url(imagenes/basico/compresion/articulo.jpg);
background-size: cover;}

.compresion_multibanda
{background-image: url(imagenes/intermedio/compresion_multibanda/articulo.jpg);
background-size: cover;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<input type="button" id="filter-btn" value="Apply">
<table class="tabla_basico" id="tablaPiola">
   <tr>
      <td class="automatizaciones">
         <div class="overlay_basico"><a href="/">AUTOMATIZACIONES</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="bpm_a_ms">
         <div class="overlay_intermedio"><a href="/">BPM A MS</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="compresion">
         <div class="overlay_basico"><a href="compresion.html">COMPRESIÓN</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="compresion_multibanda">
         <div class="overlay_intermedio"><a href="/">COMPRESIÓN MULTIBANDA</a></div>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

---

Some other notes not directly related to the main problem:

- That code falls prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You never declare `i`, `a`, or `txtValue` so you end up creating global variables when you assign to them. I recommend using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) in all code so you get an error when you try to do that.
- FWIW, I see you're using ES2015+ features (`const`, for instance), so you could use a `for-of` loop instead of a `for` loop. `for-of` is a bit less typing. But you may need to polyfill iterability on some platforms. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057817/157247) shows how to do that.

Comment: This works fine in terms of filtering but I want them to appear at the start of the table instead of staying in their original table position.

Comment: I'll give all that a look, I've just learnt JavaScript through some courses on codecademy so I'm pretty much a begginer in the subject.
Yep, now they remain at 25% so thats cool.

Comment: That last update seems to apply a unique filter in every row, so every element that applies to the condition moves to the first/second/third/fourth <td> of each row (in case there are up to 4 elements in that row appliying to the condition), instead of filling the first row, then the second, etc.

Comment: @Sztraji - I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Solved it, made a whole new <div> table/grid instead of an actual <table> so I didn't have to deal with different row tags and it worked great! :) Thanks for the help