# TypeError: radioButton[i] is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, undefined-behavior

I have a simple JS code which needs to get the IDs from each radio button input, and then create labels with the same IDs for each radio button. The code works, but I am getting an error message as written in the title. How to get rid of it?

And I saw there's already a similar question but it didn't solve my problem at all.

```js
function addLabels() {
  var radioButton = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (var i = 0; i <= radioButton.length; i++) {
    var radioButtonId = radioButton[i].id;
    var label = "<label for='" + radioButtonId + "'></label>";
    $(label).insertAfter(radioButton[i]);
  }
}

addLabels();
```

```html
<div class="slider-nav">
<input type="radio" name="slider-button" id="radio-button0">
<input type="radio" name="slider-button" id="radio-button1">
<input type="radio" name="slider-button" id="radio-button2">
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `=` from the `for` loop condition, you're looping past the last index of the collection.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you so much! Exactly that caused this error. Now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues I can see:

1. `getElementsByTagName` returns a **live** collection. If you change the DOM in ways that affect the elements (for instance, by moving them), that change is reflected in the collection.

   If you don't want that, get a `NodeList` from `querySelectorAll` instead (`document.querySelectorAll("input")`; `NodeList`s are snapshots, not live collections. Or since you're using jQuery, use a jQuery set (`$("input")`). They're also snapshots.

   That said, looking more closely at your code, I don't think you're doing anything that would affect the collection.
2. You're using `<= radioButton.length` instead of just `< radioButton.length`. You should go `0` through `< radioButton.length`. If you use a jQuery set, you can use its `each` method instead. If you use the `NodeList` from `querySelectorAll`, in modern environments (or if you [polyfill it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057817/157247)), you can use its `forEach` method.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered! That character caused the error, now everything works perfectly and I understand my mistake! All three answers are the same, I don't know which one to accept. If I could, I would accept them all!

Answer (score 2):

`i <= radioButton.length` will try to access the non existent element. Iterate till the length is less than the length of the collection

```js
function addLabels() {
  var radioButton = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < radioButton.length; i++) {
    var radioButtonId = radioButton[i].id;
    var label = "<label for='" + radioButtonId + "'>" + radioButtonId + "</label>";
    $(label).insertAfter(radioButton[i]);
  }
}

addLabels();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='test1'>
<input type='checkbox' id='test2'>
<input type='checkbox' id='test3'>
<input type='checkbox' id='test4'>
<input type='checkbox' id='test5'>
<input type='checkbox' id='test6'>
```

Alternatively you can use spread syntax to convert the collection to array and use arrray operator and template literal for a cleaner code

```js
function addLabels() {
  [...document.getElementsByTagName("input")].forEach((item) => {
    var radioButtonId = item.id;
    var label = `<label for=${radioButtonId}>${radioButtonId}</label>`;
    $(label).insertAfter(item);

  });

}

addLabels();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='test1'>
<input type='checkbox' id='test2'>
<input type='checkbox' id='test3'>
<input type='checkbox' id='test4'>
<input type='checkbox' id='test5'>
<input type='checkbox' id='test6'>
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered! That character caused the error, now everything works perfectly and I understand my mistake! All three answers are the same, I don't know which one to accept. If I could, I would accept them all!

Answer (score 1):

You have a minor mistake in your code.

If the flag `i` starts with 0 then it should be less than it's the length.

You are trying to access an additional element that does not exist in DOM.

Please replace your line -

```
for (var i = 0; i <= radioButton.length; i++)
```

With

```
for (var i = 0; i < radioButton.length; i++)
```

OR

```
for (var i = 1; i <= radioButton.length; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered! That character caused the error, now everything works perfectly and I understand my mistake! All three answers are the same, I don't know which one to accept. If I could, I would accept them all!