# identifying the classList of a created element JS

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a todo List and I'm stuck in filtering the list items of the todos list. I'm not even sure where the problem is.

I create a list item and when clicking the check icon I add a class of "completed" to it and in another function I iterate the list childNotes and try to filter the ones that have that completed class but keep getting an error of:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined at app.js:84. at NodeList.forEach () at HTMLSelectElement.filterTodo (app.js:76)" even thought the list has list items

code : https://codepen.io/mullerz/pen/vYNeMEO?editors=1111

````
if(item.classList[0] === "complete-btn"){
        const todo = item.parentElement;
        todo.classList.toggle("completed"); 
     }  
}


function filterTodo(e){
    const todos = todoList.childNodes;
    //console.log(todos)

    todos.forEach(function(todo, index){
        //if(index === 0){return}

        console.log({todo})
        switch (e.target.value) {

            case "all" :
                console.log(todo.classList)
                todo.style.display = "flex";

            break;

            case "completed" :

                if(todo.classList.contains("completed") ){
                console.log(todo.classList)

                    todo.style.display = "flex";
                }
                else{
                    todo.style.display = "none";
                }
```
````

Comment: Please make your runnable examples **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button), rather than offsite (or in addition to). When you make your runnable example off-site, it's all too easy to leave out some essential part of it in the question text. (But nice one, I think everything essential **is** there in this question.) [Here's how to do a Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 0):

Not all child nodes are *elements*, some are Text nodes or Comment nodes or similar. Only elements have a `style` property.

You might want [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) rather than [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes). `children` is just child elements, skipping other kinds of nodes. But note that officially, the [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) you get from `children` doesn't have `forEach` (although it does in some implementations). (The [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) you get from `childNodes` is defined to have `forEach`, and reliably does on modern browsers [only].)

Alternatively, keep using `childNodes`, but then check `node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE` before looking for the `style` property.

---

If you want, you can polyfill `forEach` on `HTMLCollection` (and on `NodeList` in older browsers that don't have it natively); I describe how to do that [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057817/157247).

Answer (score 0):

I found several issues in your code. You can check my solution.

I've used the `change` event to trigger the filter function also used `const todos = [...todoList.children];` to get the required children.

```js
console.clear();

const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
const todoButton = document.querySelector(".todo-button");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");
const filterOption = document.querySelector(".filter-todo");

todoButton.addEventListener("click", addTodo)
todoList.addEventListener("click", deleteCheck)
filterOption.addEventListener("change", filterTodo)


function addTodo(e){


 e.preventDefault();
 
 // create div that will have the line items of each task
 const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
 todoDiv.classList.add("todo");

 // create line item
 const newTodo = document.createElement("li");
 newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
 newTodo.classList.add("todo-item");
 todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);

 // create completion button
 const completeButton = document.createElement("button");
 completeButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
 completeButton.classList.add("complete-btn");
 todoDiv.appendChild(completeButton);

 // create discard button
 const trashButton = document.createElement("button");
 trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
 trashButton.classList.add("trash-btn");
 todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);

 // attach de div we just created to the existing ul in the html
 todoList.appendChild(todoDiv)
 // clear
 todoInput.value = "";

}


// delete item

function deleteCheck(e){

 const item = e.target;

 if(item.classList[0] === "trash-btn"){ 
  const todo = item.parentElement;
  todo.classList.add("fall");
  // check if transition of the class css "fall" has ended and then remove the item
  todo.addEventListener("transitionend", function(){
   todo.remove();
  });
 }

// check mark
 if(item.classList[0] === "complete-btn"){
  const todo = item.parentElement;
   todo.classList.toggle("completed"); 

  }
 
}


function filterTodo(e){
 const todos = [...todoList.children];
 
 todos.forEach(function(todo, index){
  switch (e.target.value) {

   case "all" :
    todo.style.display = "flex";

   break;

   case "completed" :
    
    if(todo.classList.contains("completed") ){

     todo.style.display = "flex";
    }
    else{
     todo.style.display = "none";
    }
   break;

   case "uncompleted" :
    if(!todo.classList.contains("completed")){
     todo.style.display = "flex";
    }
    else{
     todo.style.display = "none";

    }

  }
 })

}
```

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #f6d365, #fda0a5);
 color:white;
 font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
 min-height:100vh;

}
header{
 font-size:1.5rem;


}
header, form{
 min-height:20vh;
 display:flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

form input, form button{
 padding:0.5rem;
 font-size:2rem;
 border:none;
 background: white;
}

form button{
 background:#d88771;
 color:white;
}
form button:hover{
 background:white ;
 color:#d88771;
}

.todo-container{
 display:flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.todo-list{
 min-width:20%;
 list-style:none;
}

.todo{
 margin: .5rem;
 background: white;
 color:black;
 font-size:1.5rem;
 display:flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items:center;
 transition: all .5s ease;
}

.todo li{ flex:1; }

.trash-btn, .complete-btn{
 background: #ff6f47;
 color:white;
 border:none;
 padding:1rem;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:1rem;
}

.complete-btn{
 background:rgb(73, 204, 73);
 color:white;
 border:none;
 padding:1rem;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:1rem;
}

.todo-item{ padding:0rem .5rem; }

.fa-trash, .fa-check{ pointer-events: none; }

.completed{
 text-decoration:line-through;
 opacity:.5;
}

.fall{
 transform: translateY(8rem) rotateZ(20deg);
 opacity:0;
}
select{
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 appearance:none;
 outline:none;
 border:none;
}

.select{
 margin: 1rem;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
select{
 color: #ff6f47;
 width: 10rem;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 1rem;
}

.select::after{
 content: "\25BC";
 position:absolute;
 background: #ff6f47;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 padding:1rem;
 pointer-events:none;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.select:hover::after{
 background: white;
 color:#ff6f47;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
<header>
  <h1>To do List</h1>
 </header> 
 <form>
  <input type="text" class="todo-input">
  <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
   <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="select">
   <select name="todos" class="filter-todo">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="completed">Completed</option>
    <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </form>
 <div class="todo-container">
  <ul class="todo-list">
  </ul>
 </div>
```