# TypeError: element.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am wanting to make a Chrome extension that will replace the word 'Corona Virus' with my word of choice. In my script.js I am using a recursive function that checks to see if there are any ChildNodes. `

```
replaceText(document.body)

function replaceText(element){
    if(element.hasChildNodes()){
        element.forEach(replaceText);
    } else if(element.nodeType === Text.TEXT_NODE) {
        element.textContent = element.textContent.replace(/coronavirus/gi,
            'Blehh')
    }
}`
```

In my console I am receiving an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: element.hasChildNodes.forEach is not a function` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`. Any reason why this error is happening?

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code you posted. But in that code snippet, you probably meant `element.childNodes.forEach(replaceText)`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The error message I get is *element.forEach is not a function*. I can't see any way it could get to that line and then error because `element` is `undefined`

Comment: Hang on. Your question title says `element.forEach` is not a function, which is a **completely different** error message. Try providing an [mcve] and quote the *actual* error that code gives you. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: It sounds like you tried a bunch of things (which explains why you've quoted multiple error messages), but fundamentally, `forEach` just isn't provided by elements. Not on the element itself, and certainly not on its `hasChildNodes` function (that doesn't make any sense). Rather than guessing at what things have, it's well worth your time to use a decent reference, such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements don't have a `forEach` method. (Neither does the `hasChildNodes` function that they have.) They aren't arrays or `NodeList`s.

On modern browsers, `element.childNodes` has `forEach` because it's a  [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and a couple of years ago they got `forEach` (and iterability), so:

```
element.childNodes.forEach(replaceText);
```

On older browsers that haven't added that yet, you can use `Array.from` to get a true array, then use `forEach`:

```
Array.from(element.childNodes).forEach(replaceText);
```

Or you can polyfill it on `NodeList`, [as I show in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057817/157247).