# How do I select one <input> at a time with javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, leaflet

I have the following code that is generated by leaflet. Leaflet does not use the proper syntax in their HTML and so this is a bit difficult.

I am looking to create `<button>` elements that correspond to each `<input>` so that I can trigger them without having to deal with applying styling on top of leaflet.

```html
<div class="leaflet-control-layers-base">
  <label>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157">
      <span> All Activities</span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157">
      <span> 
        <span id="icons1">Beaches</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157">
      <span>
        <span id="icons2">Wading pools</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157">
      <span>
        <span id="icons3">Swimming pools</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Give them all a unique ID?

Comment: do you mean to add a button beside each input?

Comment: *How do I select one <input> at a time* =>  thats already happening

Comment: I cannot edit this HTML because it is generated by leaflet. If I were to give each one and I'd I would need to do so with javascript, so same problem. I want to hide the inputs off screen and use a `<button>` with `onclick=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should think into a other direction.

Don't try to replace/use the leaflet layer controler to get what you want. I recommend that you listen on a button click directly and then add / remove the layers:

```
<button onclick="showBeachesLayer()">Beaches Layer</button>



function showBeachesLayer(){
  map.addLayer(beaches)
  if(map.hasLayer(swimmingpools)){ // for each layer what should be removed
    map.removeLayer(swimmingpools);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/bpy297kz/

Answer (score 0):

You can select all of those inputs with `querySelectorAll`:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input.leaflet-control-layers-selector");
```

That gives you a `NodeList`, which you can loop through via `forEach` (in modern browsers) or index into via `length` and `[]`.

For instance, adding a button:

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll("input.leaflet-control-layers-selector");
for (const input of list) {
    input.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "afterend",
        "<button type=button>Some Button</button>"
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="leaflet-control-layers-base">
    <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> All Activities</span></div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> <span id="icons1">Beaches</span></span></div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> <span id="icons2">Wading pools</span></span></div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> <span id="icons3">Swimming pools</span></span></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

For slightly older browsers, you may need to use `forEach` instead, and on even older ones, you may need to polyfill `forEach`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057817/157247) goes into that part of things in detail.

Or if you wanted the `button`s at the end of the `span`s:

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll("input.leaflet-control-layers-selector");
for (const input of list) {
    input.nextElementSibling.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "afterend",
        "<button type=button>Some Button</button>"
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="leaflet-control-layers-base">
    <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> All Activities</span></div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> <span id="icons1">Beaches</span></span></div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> <span id="icons2">Wading pools</span></span></div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <div><input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_157"><span> <span id="icons3">Swimming pools</span></span></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Etc.