# How to add divs to multiple instances of a class?

Tags: javascript

I have been using some code to add divs to my buttons for styling using the code below, it works fine on the first instance of the button but it does not add the divs to any buttons after that? what am I missing? I'm willing to learn and have tried to Google this but I'm getting buried deep in things I don't fully understand just yet. Would be great if any answer could be in plain Javascript and not jQuery.

**JS**

```js
// Parent Element
const el = document.querySelector(".myclass");

// Create New Element
const newEl = document.createElement("span");
newEl.classList= "cm-bg";

const newEl2 = document.createElement("span");
newEl2.classList= "cm-base";

// Insert New Element BEFORE an Element
el.before(newEl);
el.before(newEl2);
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
   <a href="#" class="elementor-button-link" role="button">
      <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
         <span class="elementor-button-text">Click here</span>
      </span>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add it to your classlist, can you share also your html

Comment: Note: Although it does work, don't use `newEl.classList= "cm-bg";`. Use either `newEl.className= "cm-bg";` (`className` instead of `classList`) or `newEl.classList.add("cm-bg");` (the `add` method on `classList`) instead.

Comment: @Alex - Believe it or not, `el.classList = "x"` works and is even specified behavior. Sadly. :-)

Comment: my html is


<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
   <a href="#" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-sm" role="button">
         <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
         <span class="elementor-button-text">Click here</span>
  </span>
          </a>
  </div>

Comment: @Matu - Please use the "edit" link just under the tags under the question to improve the question, rather than posting code/markup in comments.

Comment: Yes I couldn't find the edit, found a little bit after posting in comment ;)

Comment: *"Insert New Element AFTER an Element"* Your code inserts **before**, not after, the element.

Answer (score 2):

`querySelector` finds the **first** matching element in the document. So your code always adds elements to the first `.myclass` in your document.

If you want to find **all** matching elements and update them, you use `querySelectorAll` and loop through the results:

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll(".elementor-button-wrapper");
for (const el of list) {
    // Create New Element
    const newEl = document.createElement("span");
    newEl.className = "cm-bg";      // *** See comment on question
    const newEl2 = document.createElement("span");
    newEl2.className = "cm-base";   // *** See comment on question

    // Insert New Element AFTER an Element
    el.before(newEl);
    el.before(newEl2);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll(".elementor-button-wrapper");
for (const el of list) {
    // Create New Element
    const newEl = document.createElement("span");
    newEl.className = "cm-bg";      // *** See comment on question
    const newEl2 = document.createElement("span");
    newEl2.className = "cm-base";   // *** See comment on question

    // Insert New Element AFTER an Element
    el.before(newEl);
    el.before(newEl2);
}
```

```css
.cm-bg::after {
    content: "cm-bg"
}
.cm-base::after {
    content: "cm-base"
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="elementor-button-link" role="button">
        <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
            <span class="elementor-button-text">Click here</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="elementor-button-link" role="button">
        <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
            <span class="elementor-button-text">Click here</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="elementor-button-link" role="button">
        <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
            <span class="elementor-button-text">Click here</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="elementor-button-link" role="button">
        <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
            <span class="elementor-button-text">Click here</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

That relies on the `NodeList` from `querySelectorAll` being iterable, which it is in modern environments (and per specification). If you need to handle older environments, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057817/157247) for how to polyfill it. Or just use a `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    const el = list[i];
    // ...rest of loop body here...
}
```

---

Side note: Beware that no version of IE supports the [`before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/before) method on `ChildNode`. IE is actively being discontinued by Microsoft, but still has significant presence in large corporate or government installations.

FWIW, you can use `insertAdjacentHTML` which is universally supported and lets you write the elements as HTML (if that's desireable):

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll(".elementor-button-wrapper");
for (const el of list) {
    el.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforestart",
        "<span class=cm-bg></span><span class=cm-base></span>"
    );
}
```

Or just use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore):

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll(".elementor-button-wrapper");
for (const el of list) {
    // Create New Element
    const newEl = document.createElement("span");
    newEl.className = "cm-bg";      // *** See comment on question
    const newEl2 = document.createElement("span");
    newEl2.className = "cm-base";   // *** See comment on question

    // Insert New Element AFTER an Element
    el.parentElement.insertBefore(newEl, el);
    el.parentElement.insertBefore(newEl2, el);
}
```

Comment: I have added this and it is still only affecting my frist instance of the button

Comment: @Matu - I'm afraid you must have not quite applied it correctly. I'd do a live example, but there is no element with the class `myclass` in your HTML, so I have no idea which element you want to add these `span`s near.

Comment: I'm testing it here https://codepen.io/matthew-reilly/pen/NWbNxoY

Comment: I updated the original post also to include the class

Comment: @Matu - I've been assuming that this code runs in response to some event. Are you trying to add to **multiple** buttons in this code, all at once?

Comment: As in the Codepen, there will be more than one button on the page at any time and I want the two new spans added to the CSS class .elementor-button-text for each one.

Comment: @Matu - The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future.

Comment: @Matu - I've updated to show handling a list of elements.

Comment: Thanks, I will take that on board with the whole code etc, I got the code working but now the text in the button is being drawn over by the hover background effect, I have tried .after and higher z-index on .elementor-button-text but it is still below... any ideas? actually I just tried on my site and it is fine, it is Codepen that was having the issue. thanks for your help