# Knyaz.Optimus headless browser not returning elements

Tags: vb.net, headless-browser

I am using Optimus as a headless browser in vb.net, specifically to locate html elements on a page.

The Optimus engine initiates and retrieves a page ok - I can see the full html - a google rearch result as it happens. However

`Dim LClasses As ITokenList = _engine.Document.ClassList` returns a 0 length list (even though I can see classes in the page source) and
`Dim LNodes As List(Of Node) = _engine.Document.ChildNodes` returns only 2 nodes: html and head - even though there are of course dozens of other nodes.

Is vb.net supported? Am I doing something stupid?

(I have posted this same question on the Optimus Github page - apologies if duplicating it is bad form)

Comment: On further investigation it looks as if I have to build some kind of recursive function to do this - the engine just returns child nodes and classes for the current element.

Comment: The developer has said: 1. Document.ClassList should be empty. In real browsers this property is undefined.
2. ChildNodes returns children, not descendants. Most often there are only two such nodes: DocType and html.
3. I can not guarantee that vb.net will work. But I see no reason why this should not be.  Also You can use one of the approaches suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325278/how-can-i-get-all-descendant-elements-for-parent-container

Comment: Ok here is how I got it to work: ...
Imports Knyaz.Optimus
Imports Knyaz.Optimus.Dom.Elements
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports Knyaz.Optimus.Dom.Interfaces
...
initiate the optimus engine (here called "_engine") and get a webpage
...
Dim coll As ReadOnlyCollection(Of IElement)
coll = _engine.Document.Body.QuerySelectorAll("*") 'this returns a collection of all the elements in the webpage - woohoo!