# Selecting DOM elements based on ID values

Tags: javascript

I have some textboxes in the DOM someting like

```
<INPUT id=txtQuantity587117 />
<INPUT id=txtQuantity587118 />
<INPUT id=txtQuantity587119 />
<INPUT id=txtQuantity587111 />
<INPUT id=txtQuantity587112 />
```

The elements are all nested and are not under any particular parent node.

Is there a way to select all the input elements with id text that starts with "txtQuantity".

I want a way with javascript and not with Jquery. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617480/how-to-get-all-elements-which-name-starts-with-some-string -- Should help

Comment: Can't you alter the code to put a class on them? It would be simpler and quicker to retrieve them.

Comment: using a class would make a load of sense, but i think that the other 2 answers should be considered over the one that is marked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In modern browsers (and also IE8... *now verified*) you can use `document.querySelectorAll()` the `attribute-starts-with` selector.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("input[id^=txtQuantity]");
```

Comment: works on ie9+. ie8 supports css2 selectors and ^= is not in the css2 spec :(

Comment: @CoryDanielson: Are you sure that applies to `.querySelectorAll()`? In IE8 it supports a broader array of selectors that its stylesheet support.

Comment: MDN's documentation says that querySelectorAll only supports CSS2 selectors in ie8. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: @CoryDanielson: Yes, looks like you're right. I'll update. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @CoryDanielson: Oddly, I just tested in IE8 Browser & Document mode using the Developer tools, and it works fine. Even the MSDN page I found wasn't entirely clear on that.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some code that doesn't rely on any "modern" API calls apart from `Array.filter`, which is a lot easier to shim than `document.querySelectorAll`:

```
var els = [].filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), function(el) {
    return /^txtQuantity/.test(el.id);
});
```

With the appropriate shim this should work on any browser from MSIE 5.5 onwards.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/9jEzj/

Comment: Pretty sure `[].slice()` with the `this` value set to a NodeList or HTMLCollection *(or any non-native collection)* will fail in IE8 and lower. Though it's completely unnecessary anyway. You could just set the `this` value of `.filter()`. Since you'll be shimming it, it'll then work.

Answer (score 3):

no problem...

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var matches = [];

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    var input = inputs[i];
    if(input.id.indexOf("txtQuantity") == 0){
        matches.push(input);
    }
}

//matches will be an array of the matched elements
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/GKHpJ/)

Comment: Perfect for my scenario. Thanks a ton.