# Function didn't work with document.all

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Can someone help me to solve this problem

Javascript Code:

```
function CheckAll(pObj) { 
      var mCurrStatus; 
      mCurrStatus = pObj.checked; 
      var mObjList; mObjList = document.all["process"]; 
      for (x = 0; x <= 2; x++) { 
          var Obj;
          Obj = mObjList[x];
          Obj.checked = mCurrStatus; 
      } 
}
```

asp-classic code:

```
 response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox name=process_1 " 
 response.Write "/>box1</td>" 
 response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox name=process_2 " 
 response.Write "/>box2</td>"
```

and this is my selectall box :

```
response.Write "<th align=left><input type=checkbox onclick=CheckAll(this)></th>"
```

how do i select thoses boxes when i click the select all box (it's seem the function doesn't work)
please help me instead of giving me the example... thanks so much for you guy help~

Updated:

i refer to Roland suggestion and make the new function  but doesn't work any idea?

function CheckAll() {

```
var eles = [];
var len = elems.length;
//var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var elems = tab.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (elems[i].name.indexOf('process_') == 0) {
        eles.push(elems[i]);
    }
}

//var elems = tab.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var x = 0; x < len; x++) {
    if (elems[x].type == "checkbox") {
        elems[x].checked = true;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Also, you can edit your question ...

Comment: To Dimitar , i have upload those code in comment field

Comment: `document.all` is non-standard and deprecated. Use `document.getElementById` or `document.getElementsByName`

Comment: @Luk you really won't see code in comments. ad 1 because comments do not support indents & highlights & ad 2 because comments will be deleted by cleaner sooner or later

Comment: Dear Roland  , i had tried to use those getElements , but those boxes name are process_1 , process_2 ...> process_9 , and when i use document.getElementById , only 1 id i cant select (and i cant use table becasue the design problem)

Comment: To Vogel ,  thx for teling me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617480/how-to-get-all-elements-which-name-starts-with-some-string

Comment: use @ to notify someone, who is not the ownwer of the question / answer

Comment: @Roland  How Could i use your example into my funciton?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can select and check all the checkboxes:

First find your elements (this is vanilla.js):

```
// will find all the html elements that have a name containing the value passed
var find = function(name) {
    // you can optimize this part a bit (pass the tag name)
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var elementName = elements[i].name;
        if(elementName !== undefined && elementName.indexOf(name) != -1) {
            results.push(elements[i]);              
        }
    }
    return results;
};
```

Then this is how you use this "utility" function to check all:

```
var checkAll = function() {
    var checkBoxes = find("process");
    for(var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        checkBoxes[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BuacB/1/

As a side note, this bit here is not valid html (you're missing some quotes):

```
response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox name=process_1 " 
response.Write "/>box1</td>"
```

I beleive it needs to be:

```
response.Write "<td nowrap><input type='checkbox' name='process_1' " 
response.Write "/>box1</td>"
```

Comment: @Dimitrov   two functions i had refer to your code  (find your elements) & "utility" function"   but i  still cant seelct one of my boxes

Comment: @Luk Did you fix your markup as well ? When you say "one of my boxes" does it mean it works for the rest ?

Comment: response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox name=process_1 "
    if mEditRecMode and ConvertNullToString(mConsigneeArray(9))="1" then response.Write " checked"
    response.Write "/>box1</td>"    <-- there is one of my boxes  those code from boxes are fine ,  i just wanna how i can use your function into my program , could you please help?  thx~